# How to change the current Git repository in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I would like to change my Git repository.

I have created another Git repository and I would like to connect it to the new one.

Where can I list all the providers and change it?

Answer (score 4):

Since the latest VSCode 1.19 version, you can have **[multi-root folders](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces)**

That means you can open a new folder (the one with a `.git/` subfolder inside) representing your second repository.
VSCode will detect that Git repo, and use Git commands accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use set_url command :

```
git remote set-url origin {your-new-url}
```

You can also use the add command to have multiple remotes :

```
git remote add origin {your-new-url}
```

Comment: "Git: fatal: couldn't find remote ref main"

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the current git repository with (git remote remove “name of git”)
And then you can add the one that you want with (git remote add “name of git” url of git

Answer (score 0):

try to checkout `git remote -v`
and remove some exists by `git remote remove origin`

references:
https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists-error/